# ORA-00900: Invalid SQL Statement position:0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy tratando de sustitur los codigos de trabajo en esa consulta por las letras que le siguen, pero cuando trato de correr la consulta, me da el error que apare como titulo, la base de datos que estamos usando es la de practica que proporciona Oracle, es una tarea,  gracias de antemano.

```
SELECT DECODE(job_id,
                   ad_pres,     'A',
                   st_man,      'B',
                   it_prog,     'C',
                   sa_rep,      'D',
                   st_clerk,    'E',
                                'None of the above') AS "Calicacion de empleados"
FROM hr.employees;
```

Comment: Lee la documentación: [aquí es un buen lugar para empezar](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)

Comment: He leido en mas de 8 foros diferentes y todos me dicen lo mismo, incluyendo el foro que me enviaste...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_name, DECODE(job_id,
                   'AD_PRES',    'A',
                   'ST_MAN'  ,    'B',
                   'IT_PROG'  ,   'C',
                   'SA_REP'    ,  'D',
                   'ST_CLERK'   , 'E',
                                'None of the above') AS "Calicacion de empleados"
FROM hr.employees;
```

Comment: Es la solución a tu pregunta?